# Does using torch.where cause the model's parameter gradients to become zero?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

Here is the `forward()` method of my pytorch model:

```py
    def forward(self, x, output_type, *unused_args, **unused_kwargs):
        gru_output, gru_hn = self.gru(x)
        # Decoder (Graph Adjacency Reconstruction)
        for data_batch_idx in range(x.shape[0]):
            pred = self.decoder(gru_output[data_batch_idx, -1, :])  # gru_output[-1] => only take last time-step
            pred_graph_adj = pred.reshape(1, -1) if data_batch_idx == 0 else torch.cat((pred_graph_adj, pred.reshape(1, -1)), dim=0)
        if output_type == "discretize":
            bins = torch.tensor(self.model_cfg['output_bins']).reshape(-1, 1)
            num_bins = len(bins)-1
            bins = torch.concat((bins[:-1], bins[1:]), dim=1)
            discretize_values = np.linspace(2, 4, num_bins)
            for lower, upper, discretize_value in zip(bins[:, 0], bins[:, 1], discretize_values):
                pred_graph_adj = torch.where((pred_graph_adj <= upper) & (pred_graph_adj > lower), discretize_value, pred_graph_adj)
            pred_graph_adj = torch.where(pred_graph_adj < bins.min(), 2, pred_graph_adj)

        return pred_graph_adj
```

And here is the snippet of training:

```py
                pred = self.forward(x, output_type=self.model_cfg['output_type'])
                batch_loss = self.loss_fn(pred, y)
                self.optimizer.zero_grad()
                batch_loss.backward()
                self.optimizer.step()
                self.scheduler.step()
```

1. When `output_type` is not  `"discretize"` (not using `torch.where`), `sum([p.grad.sum() for p in self.decoder.parameters()])` will be non-zero.

   - But When `output_type` is  `"discretize"` (using `torch.where`), `sum([p.grad.sum() for p in self.decoder.parameters()])` will be zero.
2. I've check the `batch_loss`, it's not zero.
3. I've check all the `require_grad` of weight of model, they are True.
4. I've check computational graph, `pred` and `batch_loss` are connect to model's weight.

My questions are:

1. Does using `torch.where` cause the model's parameter gradients to become zero?
2. If `torch.where` won't cause that, what's other possible reasons?

---

### Update info:

- The initial values of `pred_graph_adj` are between **-1 ~ 1**.

  - But I've check the values range of final `pred_graph_adj` (after `torch.where`), they are between **2 ~ 4**.
- The specific values of args of `torch.where`(`lower` and `upper` and `discretize_value`) in each for-loop are:

```
(lower, upper] -> discrete_values:
(-1, -0.25] -> 2
(-0.25, 0.25] -> 3
(0.25, 1] -> 4
```

Comment: Is it possible that initially all of the vales in `pred_graph_adj` satisfy the conditions s.t. they are being replaced with either `bins.min()` or `upper` or `lower`? Seems that none of these variables will affect the gradient so you could have an initial condition problem

Comment: `torch.where(condition,a,b)` is differentiable w.r.t. `a` and `b` but not `condition`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I try to express more detailed information in original post.
I type it in the section of **Update Info**.
Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I don't understand the notation in your update but it sounds like all of the values in `pred_adj_graph` are being replaced. This would prevent the gradient from backpropogating farther than the `torch.where` statement because the partial derivative of the output of the where statement with respect to `pred_graph_adj` is 0. Which explains your lack of gradient values

Comment: Yes, I replace all of the values in `pred_adj_graph`. I don't know this would prevent the gradient from backpropagating. @DerekG Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I have enough information about your issue to answer it at this point. Some prelimiaries:

- You are confused why the gradient for loss with respect to your model parameters is 0.
- The outputs from your model pass through a `torch.where` statement before being used to compute loss.
- That `torch.where` statement replaces some model outputs that fall outside of a certain range with some other values (`lower`,`upper`,`discretize_values`) which are generated independently of the model outputs.
- Initially, the outputs of your model fall in a range such that ALL model outputs are replaced by these other values.

Let's use some simpler variable names to avoid the confusion of inplace assignments. Let `output` be your model outputs. Let `replace` be the replacement values. Let `condition` be the condition statement. The simplified expression is something like:

```
result = torch.where(condition, output, replace)
loss = f(result) # some arbitrary function
```

It is true that the partial derivative of loss w.r.t. output is not ALWAYS zero. However, `torch.where` is a simple indexing statement, meaning that the partial derivative of the output with respect to each of the inputs is 1 for all selected elements and zero for unselected elements. Since all  of `output` is unselected, partial of `result` with respect to `output` is zero. Partial of `result` with respect to `replace` is non-zero, but these elements are not a function of the model parameters or outputs (and furthermore are defined with a numpy statement, a dead giveaway that the function graph will not flow backwards past `discretize_values`.)

So, while your problem is not structural (e.g. it is possible for loss to be backpropogated to the model parameters) your initial conditions are such that your optimization routine is stuck in a local minimum where all elements are always replaced and the gradient with respect to the model parameters is always zero.

But wait!! The conditional expresssion `condition` is itself a function of the model outputs `output`. So the gradient should still be backpropogated due to this.  While technically true, `torch.where` is not differentiable with respect to condition (think about the fact that any, arbitrarily complex, horrendously non-differentiable expression can be used as `condition` provided it is of type `bool`, so this derivative would be noisy, messy, and often undefined). For this reason, `torch.where` is only differentiable with respect to the other inputs (i.e. `output` and `replace` here).

To solve your issue you could try random parameter initialization, or else choose not to replace values with `torch.where` at the beginning to allow for initial convergence, or come up with some other clever solution that is more heavily dependent on your actual use case.
Hope this helps!